# undo git force push when local repo is deleted

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a situation where I force pushed a old copy of the code from local to gitlab loosing all my new changes. I was looking to find out the last best commit and came to know about reflog however in my case, I deleted the local copy after the force push. So, when I cloned and run git reflog , it does not show old history. What should I do here? It looks like git reflog works on the local repo.

Comment: If you navigate to the part of gitlab that documents your force push, does it show the old commit? If so, you may be able to use that reference until it's cleaned up with `git gc` eventually

Comment: what do you mean? gitlab ui does not show anything like force push as such though github shows.

Comment: I've never force pushed and deleted my local history, so I was making a best guess at what might be possible. If you can find out an old commit SHA, you can search it in the project and restore from there

Comment: Do you mean get an old commit, reset hard to that commit and force push again?

Comment: You won't be able to hard reset to that commit locally because it won't exist in a new local copy - git won't bother to clone orphaned commits. But if you search an old commit SHA in the project, you can open it as you would any other commit and do things like cherry-pick it

Comment: Your commits may also be visible on your profile, under "activity".

Comment: I got a commit on activity and I am able to hard reset to that locally and things looks fine .However, git status  says your branch b1 has diverged . What should I do here?

Comment: Well if you hard reset a branch to something else locally, then naturally your branch will be different from the remote...?

Comment: so I can just force push to go back to the old commit and start working from there?

Comment: Yes, if you want to reset the remote to the old commit, you should probably force push, while maybe making sure you've got backups this time